# Low cost IR sensor based finger gesture recognition controlled wheelchair

Tags: arduino-uno

I am doing a project in which three IR sensors are used for getting three fingers's gesture to control the movements (left, right, forward, backward) of two motors.

The threshold value of IR sensor output is 450 mV for getting  signal to be passed.

I am not understanding how to design different conditions for different movements of motors

```
int firstanalogPin = 1;     // Infrared Sensor (Right lead) connected to analog pin 1

int val1 = 0;           // variable to store the value read

int enablePin = 1;
int LeftMotorForward = 10; // Pin 10 has Left Motor connected on Arduino boards.
int LeftMotorReverse = 9; // Pin 9 has Left Motor connected on Arduino boards.

int RightMotorForward = 12; // Pin 12 has Right Motor connected on Arduino boards.
int RightMotorReverse = 13; // Pin 13 has Right Motor connected on Arduino boards

void setup()
{
    pinMode(LeftMotorForward, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
    pinMode(RightMotorForward, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
    pinMode(LeftMotorReverse, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
    pinMode(RightMotorReverse, OUTPUT);  // initialize the  pin as an output.
    Serial.begin(9600);          //  setup serial
}

void loop()
{
    val1 = analogRead(firstanalogPin);    // read the input pin
    Serial.println(val1);                           // debug value


    if (val1 >700) // forward
        digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
    else
        digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);   // turn the Left Motor ON
    if (val1 >700)
        digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);// turn the Right Motor ON 
    else
        digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);// turn the Right Motor ON
}
```

Comment: you need only one `if-else` block .... just turn on both motors in the first `if` block

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you have a problem with?  You have made the motors move forward.  So if you want just 3 different exclusive motions Forward, Left, Right.

What you could do is have 1 finger control the direction, 1 finger control left and 1 control right.

```
   OFF       ON
F1 Forwards  Backward
F2 Left Off  Left On
F3 Right Off Right On
```

So to go straight forwards F2 & F3 have to be greater than 700.

To turn left F3 > 700 && F2 < 700  (Right motor on will make the chair turn left)

To reverse then you need F1 > 700.

etc.

Ensure that the conditions are if/else ifs otherwise its going to get messy.